# Search Scope across multiple farms, Exam question 70 - 667

Tags: 2010, search, certification, 70-667

Going through exam dumps of 70 - 667 and confused with this question,

> You configure a SharePoint server 2010 Service Pack 1 (Sp1) farm.
>
> You need to use the search scope across multiple farms.
>
> What should you do?
>
> Claimed Answer is :
>
> Deploy multiple instances of the same service in a farm and assign
>   unique names to the resulting service applications.

Can someone explain the reason of the answer please, As I think we can publish existing search application to farm 2 using Manage Meta Data Service and that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have two SharePoint 2010 farms called A and B. If you want other farms to consume services (like create or consume search scopes) from the search service application, then search service must be published between one of the two Farms.

So in reality, for e.g., you will publish the search service in Farm A (during configuration) you will eventually see the option during publishing

> Select the Publish This Service Application To Other Farms check box

With the URL of the search service application appears in the Published URL(after it is being published), which means the Farm B can consume search service application from Farm A.

Comment: I am confused as it is asking you to deploy another instance of search services when we can publish one we already have or maybe I am confused lol

Comment: You can create multiple Search service applications if you have to have multiple search indexes. For example, if you want to segregate sensitive content, such as employee benefits information, into a separate index so that the content does not appear to users who do not have permission to that content, you can create a separate Search service application, which will have a separate index.